# Do temperature and pressure affect alumina properties?

Tags: pressure, temperature, structure-formation

Alumina is a ceramic, an electrical insulator, but has a relatively high thermal conductivity with a high melting point. So can all those properties change under pressure and temperature (low or high)?

Comment: High enough temperature and it melts.

Comment: *Everything* changes under temperature, and everything changes into something else under enough pressure. Please be more specific about what it is you actually have in mind.

Comment: DKNguyen Carbon under pressure become graphite and graphite are more electrically conductive than carbon from that approach does alumina become more or less conductive?

Comment: The effect of temperature on alumina's electrical conductivity is probably *negligible*.

Comment: Gert what about pressure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to know about an article considering this to some degree:

https://www.vttresearch.com/sites/default/files/pdf/tiedotteet/1996/T1792.pdf